# Permission Denial: MediaDocumentsProvider

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am getting the following exception when trying to display a URI. I think it occurs after my activity is stopped and I try to access a viable URI again. There are other questions addressing this problem but I am very confused as to how to apply any solutions to my code since my takePhotoIntent allows for a picture to either be taken or chosen from gallery (found below).

```
Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A49688
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri 
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A49688 from pid=821, uid=10238 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

My createImageFile and my takePhotoIntent:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("error","IOException");
            }catch (NullPointerException nullEx) {
                Log.w("error","NullPointerException");
            }
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }
            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            if(id.equals(HAPPY_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SURPRISED_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(AFRAID_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(UPSET_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SAD_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [Storage Access Framework client documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client):

> - Use [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) if you want your app to simply read/import data. With this approach, the app imports a copy of the data, such as an image file.
> - Use [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) if you want your app to have long term, persistent access to documents owned by a document provider. An example would be a photo-editing app that lets users edit images stored in a document provider.

As you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, your access to the Uri ends when the component is destroyed (unless you pass the Uri to a new component). You must make a copy of the file from the Uri if you'd like to continue to access it beyond the lifetime of your component or switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and [persist permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions) (possible only with document Uris).

Comment: It's mentioned in another page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Intents 

I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: My own experience suggests that not only is the permission bound to the component's life, it's also only from within _that_ context. i.e. : "your access to the Uri is restricted to the receiving component, and ends when the component is destroyed, unless…". Specifically, when you start another activity, the original activity is still alive.